# Limiting click detection on the page [javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, settimeout

I'm trying to limit the user's ability to click on an object to a certain time limit. I looked around and found that apparently, setTimeout() is the correct function to use for this type of thing. I've applied the function to my code, but its not working. I'm thinking/know now that the problem is that the setTimeout in my code isn't limiting the actual click event, which I need to do. Here is a snippet of my click code:

```
function clickRun(event) {
    var $objectVersion = correspondingObject(event.target.id);
    if (isAnyVisible() == false) { // none open
        $objectVersion.makeVisible();
    } else if (isAnyVisible() && $objectVersion.isVisible()) { //click already open div
        $objectVersion.makeInvisible();
    } else if (isAnyVisible() && $objectVersion.isVisible()==false) { //different div open
        searchAndDestroy();
        $objectVersion.delay(600).makeVisible();
    };
 };

$('.ChartLink').click(function(event) {
    setTimeout(clickRun(event),5000);
});
```

I've also created a JSFiddle to represent what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/FHC7s/

Is there a way to achieve limiting the actual click detection on the page?

Comment: Just to be clear, why are you trying to limit the user's ability to click?  If it's for entertainment purposes, then fine, but if you're trying to implement it as a security or permissions feature, then this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @Hylianpuffball Not a security or permission feature. I'm building an interactive table with expanding/compressing elements with each users' click on a certain division. The problem I'm having now is that if the user clicks on two seperate elements within ~.5 seconds of each other, both divisions expand at the same time, when only 1 should be available at a given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it is to keep track of the time of the previous click and if the current click is too soon after that, then don't do anything:

```
onClick = function(){
    if(new Date().getTime() - lastCheck < MIN_CLICK_SPACING) return;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but the trigger isn't working correctly. Here's an updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FHC7s/5/. If you change the ">" sign to "<" it works(clicks within 1 second). However, the way I want it to be (clicks more than 1 second apart) isn't working. Any suggestions? Also thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I actually just figured it out. I changed the ">" to ">=", which includes (I assume) all times greater than .5 seconds. I think that the problem was that with "> 1", the threshold that would have to pass this would be times above 1.5s, as "seconds()" doesn't keep decimals. Thanks again for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh4V3/), I've set it up so you can have the button disable itself for time `duration` after detecting a click. Just make sure to remember how your closures are operating with your `setTimeouts`.

Comment: Looks like it works well, but looks unnecessarily complicated. I just managed to get this to work using the time tracking solution that @mowwwalker gave. Thanks for the solution, though!

Comment: I agree, @mowwwalker's solution seems much more elegant, thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains an error... your line should be

```
setTimeout(function(){clickRun(event)},5000);
```

but even then I don't think that's exactly what you're looking for; that code will "delay" the click by 5 seconds, not actually prevent more clicks.  If your true intent is to ignore all clicks after a certain amount of time, then I would go with mowwalker's answer; there's no way to stop the clicks, but you can check to see if you should honor them or not.